# Shuts down / will not go up any kind of incline / replace belts and check oil, filters

Tags: lawnmower, husqvarna

My mower only has 113.8 hours on it. This would have been my 3rd season to use it. First cut of the season after about 20 to 30 minutes on it, it stalls out and will not go up an incline of any kind, just shuts down right there on the spot. After cooling off it's ready for another few minutes as long as it's flat, which I don't have much of. The dealer I bought it from has went out of business. Any ideas would be appreciated. It's a Husqvarna Riding Lawn Mower, model YT48XLS  private use

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The first place I'd look would be the carburetor. If the float is sticking, it could be running the carb out of fuel.

Comment: If it has a fuel filter, replace it first.